# How to calculate the runtime of a following code?

Tags: runtime-analysis, big-o-notation, java

Could someone explain how to calculate the Big O notation for a runtime of a snippet of a code?

```
for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<list.length; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<list.length; k++) {
            if (k%2==0) {
               list[i] += list[j];
            } else {
               list[i] += list[k];
            }
       }
   }
}
```

From my understanding, I'm thinking it's something like O(n^3) because the statement is executive n times for every i?

Comment: (This would depend on the *static evaluation* (some of which is known under the name of *code improvement* (Marketese: Code Optimization)) performed - how would you "do it using pen&paper"?) There have been discussions [What to do when the answer is already part of the question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/what-to-do-when-the-answer-is-already-part-of-the-question).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, that you denote $n$=list.length and are calculating amount of   "list[i] +=" operation. Then of course, as it is triple loop, then for $n$ times  fixed "i" from first loop you take $n$ times "j" from second loop and $n$ times "k" from most inner, third, loop. So operation "list[i] +=" will be fulfilled exactly $n^3$ times. Now knowing, that $n^3 \in O(n^3)$ you can state that complexity for whole snippet is $O(n^3)$ .

Comment: I would say that $T(n) = n^3$, so $T(n) \in O(n^3)$.

Comment: @davidbuzatto. What you mean - we cannot write $n^3 \in O(n^3)$ or something else?